# The topology of the level set of real valued harmonic function through the critical point

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u=\Re(z^n)$. Now I want to see the set $$ A=\{z:u(z)=u(0)=0\}=\{z=re^{i\theta}:r^n\cos(n\theta)=0\}. $$ Now I don't know how to prove the following statement (highlighted). Basically why does the set $A$ looks like $m$ lines passing through $0$ and intersecting with equal $\pi/n.$

[image]

Comment: Hint: $ab=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $b=0$. Apply this deep fact with $a=r^n$ and $b=\cos(n\theta)$...

Comment: Yeah I did this, which says that $\cos(n\theta)=0$. So the set is $\{(0,r\sin(n\theta):\cos(n\theta)=0\}$. But why does this represent lines?

Comment: For a given $n$ there are only finitely many $\theta$ (mod $2\pi$) with $\cos(n\theta)=0$. (I don't know where you got that $(0,r\sin(n\theta))$ from, not sure what it means. In fact the level set is $\{re^{it}:r\ge0,\cos(n\theta)=0\}$.)